# Como programar um único check-box os itens de um checklistbox?

Tags: c#

Preciso programar em um único check-box, pra quando o mesmo estiver "marcado" selecione todos meus arquivos presentes em um checklistbox e "desmarcado" o inverso.

Criei um check-box na minha aplicação 'marcar/desmarcar todos', que preciso que ao marca-lo ele selecione todos meus colaboradores que exibo em um checklistbox logo abaixo e ao desmarcá-lo, que desmarque os *flags* de todos eles desse mesmo checklistbox.

Comecei com algo assim:

```
if (checkBox1.Checked == true)
    foreach (String Arquivo in ck_Colaboradores.CheckedItems)
    {

    }
else if(checkBox1.Checked == false)
    foreach (String Arquivo in ck_Colaboradores.CheckedItems)
    {

    }
```

Comment: poderia melhorar um pouco a pergunta com mais detalhes ?

Comment: Claro @MarconcilioSouza , criei um checkbox na minha aplicação 'marcar/desmarcar todos', que preciso que ao marca-lo ele selecione todos meus colaboradores que trago em um checklistbox logo abaixo e ao desmarca-lo que desmarque os flags de todos eles desse mesmo checklistbox.

Comment: amigos...gostaria de agora, os arquivos que eu tiver selecionado eu mandar pra impressão,(todos de uma só vez, e sem mostrar pro usuário, sair diretamente na impressora padrao) como eu faço isso ? não estou habilitado pra fazer novas perguntas por enquanto qualquer coisa posto o meu código aqui !

Comment: você criar outra pergunta, simples assim.

Comment: não estou habilitado pra fazer novas perguntas por enquanto qualquer coisa posto o meu código aqui !@MarconcilioSouza

Comment: Como assim não esta habilitado ?

Comment: da uma mensagem de "Você atingiu o limite de questões" ao clicar no botao "Faça uma pergunta "

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Adicione um evento `CheckedChanged` ao `CheckBox` e altere o valor dos itens do `CheckListBox` com base no valor do `CheckBox` principal.

```
private void checkBoxMarcarDesmarcarTodos_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var isChecked = ((CheckBox)sender).Checked;

    for (int i = 0; i < checkedListBox1.Items.Count; i++)
    {
        checkedListBox1.SetItemChecked(i, isChecked);
    }
}
```

Veja funcionando:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: obrigado @LINQ, funcionou perfeitamente

Comment: De nada, @Lucão Só pra constar: você sempre pode marcar a resposta que mais te ajudou como correta usando o **✓** do lado esquerdo da resposta.

Comment: ah beleza! , não sabia.

Comment: @Lucão Mas só pode marcar uma =D

Comment: @LINQ até eu votei na sua resposta  está bem mais completa :)

Comment: @CaiqueRomero No problemo, eu votei na sua também logo que vi. Tem espaço pra todos nós aqui e as duas respostas estão corretas e merecem o aceite. Eu só comentei isso porque vi que o AP estava marcando e desmarcando, provavelmente porque pensou que poderia marcar as duas como corretas (era algo que eu me confundia no começo também).

Comment: To ligado, tudo nosso relaxa  ^^

Answer (score 3):

Você pode percorrer sua lista de checkbox e atribuir o estado do checkbox que controlará os demais, exemplo:

```
for (int i = 0; i < ck_Colaboradores.Items.Count; i++)
{
    ck_Colaboradores.SetItemChecked(i, checkBox1.Checked);
}
```

Comment: obrigado @Caique Romero, testei da sua maneira e também funcionou perfeitamente.